# How to debug "undefined method" in Ruby unit testing?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I am following a book on Ruby, I am receiving a strange error and would be glad if some one could sort it out for me.

I am looking in to collections in Ruby (very basic)

file: song_list.rb

```
class Song
    attr_accessor :name
    attr_accessor :artist
    attr_accessor :duration

    def initialize(name, artist, duration)
        @name = name
        @artist = artist
        @duration = duration
    end

    def to_s
        "SongIs -  #{@name} - #{@artist} - #{@duration}"
    end
end

class SongList
    def initialize
        @songs = Array.new
    end

    def append(song)
        @songs.push(song)
    end

    def delete_first
        @songs.shift
    end

    def delete_last
        @songs.pop
    end

    def [](index)
        @songs[index]
    end
end
```

Then I wrote a test: test_unit.rb

```
require_relative 'song_list'
require 'test/unit'
class TestSongList < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_delete
        list = SongList.new
        s1 = Song.new('title1', 'artist1', 1)
        s2 = Song.new('title2', 'artist2', 2)
        s3 = Song.new('title3', 'artist3', 3)
        s4 = Song.new('title4', 'artist4', 3)

        list.append(s1).append(s2).append(s3).append(s4)

        assert_equal(s1, list[0])
        assert_equal(s2, list[1]);
        assert_equal(s3, list[2]);
        assert_equal(s4, list[3]);

        assert_nil(list[9])

        assert_equal(s1, list.delete_first)
        assert_equal(s2, list.delete_first)
        assert_equal(s4, list.delete_last)
        assert_equal(s3, list.delete_last)
        assert_nil(list.delete_last)

    end
end
```

Now when I run the second file `ruby test_unit.rb`, I get an error. The error says that I haven't defined the function `append` in the RubyList class.

But I have, haven't I? Here is the error.

```
Run options: 

# Running tests:

[1/1] TestSongList#test_delete = 0.00 s
  1) Error:
test_delete(TestSongList):
NoMethodError: undefined method `append' for #<Array:0x9f52b30>
    test_unit.rb:11:in `test_delete'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1301:in `run'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:17:in `run'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:919:in `block in _run_suite'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:912:in `map'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:912:in `_run_suite'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:657:in `block in _run_suites'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:655:in `each'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:655:in `_run_suites'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:867:in `_run_anything'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1060:in `run_tests'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1047:in `block in _run'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1046:in `each'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1046:in `_run'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1035:in `run'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:774:in `run'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:366:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
    /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:365:in `block in autorun'

Finished tests in 0.004259s, 234.8127 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

I would be glad if you could describe to me why this happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have defined `append` on `SongList`, but you haven't defined it on `Array`.  Your `append` call here is the problem:

```
    list.append(s1).append(s2).append(s3).append(s4)
```

If you want to chain method calls like this, you'll need to adjust the `SongList#append` method to be:

```
def append(song)
    @songs.push(song)
    self
end
```

and likewise for your other methods.  Alternatively, change the initial call to be:

```
list.append(s1)
list.append(s2)
list.append(s3)
list.append(s4)
```

or use a loop:

```
[s1, s2, s3, s4].each{|s| list.append(s)}
```

The reason for the error is because ruby methods without an explicit `return` call will return the value of the last line of the method.  In your case this is `@songs.push(song)`, `@songs` is an array and `Array#push` returns an array, so your `append` method thus returns an array.  The second call in the chain tries to call `append` on the array returned from the first call and triggers the exception.

Comment: Oh I see, so ruby is kind of returning the last line of a function...  Let me test it in a while and accept. Thanks for the informative answer!

Comment: Exactly - it returns whatever the last line *evaluates to*.  So if you have a method like: `def addone(n) n + 1 ; end`, `addone(1)` would return `2`.  In this case this simple method only has 1 line, so it works as you expect, but the general principle is the same.

Comment: I am falling in love with Ruby by the moment :) Thank it worked like a charm!